# What is the easiest way to truncate an IP address to /24 in C?

Tags: c, parsing, ip-address

Is there a method that can truncate the IP address to /24?
Or, should I parse the IP address manually and do the conversion?

Edit:

Ip address is IPv4 and is stored in the Dotted decimal format surrounded by quotes as `char *`. I am expecting the /24 to be `char *` too.

Example format: **"64.233.174.94"** .

/24 expected format: **"64.233.174.0"**

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Is your IP address stored as a `char *` or as an `int` ?

Comment: How is the IP address stored?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html ?

Comment: IPv4, IPv6? Format? Dotted-quad/hex-sequence, ...? So you are not able to just count dots or colons?

Comment: As things stand there is no way for us to answer your question.

Comment: @jimmcnamara, edited..

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string specifications of the IP address and the /24 mask into binary IP addresses in network byte order, bitwise AND them together, and then convert the result into a string:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
inet_ntoa(inet_addr("64.233.174.94") & inet_addr("255.255.255.0"))
```

Comment: Don't you mean bitwise AND them?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is a better way to do it for a real program.

You do realise that the dotted decimal notation is only used to make IP address easier to deal with for humans?  In reality a computer stores an IPv4 address as a 32 bit integer.

Here is some code which sort of demonstrates how to get the integer value from the dotted decimal string.  Note this is something I quickly knocked up, and is only for demonstrating the idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* ip = "192.168.1.25";
    const char* p = ip;
    const int len = strlen(ip);
    int tmp, octet;
    unsigned accum, reducingmultiplier = 16777216;
    accum = tmp = octet = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (*p != '.') {
            tmp = *p - 0x30;
            octet *= 10;
            octet += tmp;
        }
        else {
            printf("got to dot, octet = %u\n", octet);
            accum += octet * reducingmultiplier;
            reducingmultiplier /= 256;
            octet = 0;
        }
        p++;
    }

    printf("got to end of string, final octet = %u\n", octet);
    accum += octet * reducingmultiplier;
    printf("String IP address: %s converted to an integer: %u\n", ip, accum);

    return 0;
}
```

Once you have the number stored as an integer you can AND with whatever your subnet mask to get in /24 or whatever form.  You would then convert back to string format.